# Kill process (command) which is running longer than 24hrs $pid

Tags: shell

Not able to filter Etime , please help me out to get only which process/command running more than 24hrs.

Comment: Would you paste the shell command your using to identify the process which runs more than 24hrs?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/q/181477/94862

Answer (score 2):

Give a try to this:

```
ps -eo etimes,cmd | awk '{if ($1 >= 86400) print $2}'
```

`etimes` will return the time in seconds, therefore, you can just use a `>=` desired time

You can extend this to search and kill only desired process for example:

```
kill $(ps -eo etimes,pid,cmd | awk '{if ($3 == "sleep" && $1 >= 30) print $2}')
```

In this case, it will search for `cmd` **sleep** and will only kill the process it if has been running for more than 30 seconds running.

To check if a `cmd` starts with a string, you could use:

```
ps -eo etimes,pid,cmd | awk '{if ($3~/^sle/ && $1 >= 30) print $2}'
```

The `$3~/^sle/` will check that command starts with `sle`.

Hope this can help you or give you some ideas.

Comment: you could then later just pipe `| grep http`

Comment: ps -eo etimes,pid,cmd | grep python | awk '{if ($1 >= 86400) print $2}'

Comment: I would put it at the end since first you want to find the process taking X time: `ps -eo etimes,cmd | awk '{if ($1 >= 86400) print $2}' | grep http`

Comment: Just update answer, hope can give you a better idea, in this case, it will search for command sleep `sleep 86400` and will kill it if is been running for more than 30 seconds

Comment: ps -eo pid,etime,cmd | grep http | awk 'substr($0,7,2)!=" " ' | awk {'print $1'} , ~
it's working fine for filter process which running in hrs.

Answer (score 0):

```
ps -ef
```

The equivalent of `ps -ef` is `ps -eo uid,pid,ppid,c,stime,tty,time,cmd`

```
etime      ELAPSED elapsed time since the process was started, in the
                     form [[DD-]hh:]mm:ss.
start      STARTED time the command started. If the process was started
                     less than 24 hours ago, the output format is
                     "HH:MM:SS", else it is "  <mm dd" (where Mmm is a
                     three-letter month name). See also lstart, bsdstart,
                     start_time, and stime.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this to know how long the process is been running.

```
ps -o etime= -p "your_pid"
```

Information about the flag `-o etime` it provides the elapsed time.

this will return the elapsed time

---

or another way is

```
ps -eo pid,comm,cmd,start,etime | grep -iv <your_pid>
```

Comment: i havn't updated my working code ,please find below :- 
ps -eo pid,etime,cmd | grep python| awk 'substr($0,9,1)=="-"' | awk {'print $1'}

Answer (score 0):

using `etime` of `ps` command

```
alp ❱ ps -e -o etime,pid
    ELAPSED   PID
   03:10:06     1
   03:10:06     2
   03:10:06     3
   03:10:06     5
   03:10:06     7
   03:10:06     8
   03:10:06     9
   03:10:06    10
   03:10:06    11
```

In this format since you need for `24` long time we can try (I use `03` because I did not have a `24` long time process):

```
alp ❱ ps -e -o etime,pid | grep -P '^ +03:..:..'
   03:14:16     1
   03:14:16     2
   03:14:16     3
   03:14:16     5
   03:14:16     7
   03:14:16     8
   03:14:16     9
   03:14:16    10
   03:14:16    11
```

now we can eliminate (= get rid of) those time:

```
alp ❱ ps -e -o etime,pid | grep -Po '^ +03:..:..\K +\d+'
     1
     2
     3
     5
     7
     8
     9
    10
    11
```

and eventually pass this output to `xargs`

```
alp ❱ ps -e -o etime,pid | grep -Po '^ +03:..:..\K +\d+' | xargs -I xxx echo xxx
1
2
3
5
7
8
9
10
11
```

Thus you should use `24:..:..` in the regex part and `kill` in place or `echo`